# Python - NaiveBayesClassifier - TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, naivebayes

I am trying to train some data for a classification tool I am building. I have done some simple examples and it works fine.

I am now trying to use some data from work (which is what it will be used on), and I am getting a `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable` error, the traceback is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/nicholas/Desktop/machineTraining/classLearning.py", line 13, in <module>
    cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)
  File "C:\Users\nicholas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\textblob\classifiers.py", line 205, in __init__
    super(NLTKClassifier, self).__init__(train_set, feature_extractor, format, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nicholas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\textblob\classifiers.py", line 139, in __init__
    self._word_set = _get_words_from_dataset(self.train_set) #Keep a hidden set of unique words.
  File "C:\Users\nicholas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\textblob\classifiers.py", line 63, in _get_words_from_dataset
    return set(all_words)
```

This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/nicholas\Desktop/trainData.csv", encoding='latin-1')

df['train'] = df[['Summary', 'Primary Classification']].apply(tuple, axis=1)

aTrain = df['train'].values.tolist()

train = aTrain

cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Comment: It seems some `NaN`s, so `df = df.dropna(subset=['train'])` should be help.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I am just checking that out now (I am getting a valuerror: no axis named train), but I should be able to fix that!. Ill let you know if it works when I get the axis sorted

Comment: Ok, it worked. Thanks... although I am now getting a MemoryError (might be to do with the amount of data that is going through!

Comment: `Memory errors` are very bad handled, if large data, because obviously help add RAM, but very often it is impossible :(

Comment: Ha, I wonder if I can make a business case to get my employers to build me a super computer :)... ty again jezrael